# What exactly is wrong with this translation? "El acantilado más alto que puede caer de confianza es"

Tags: traducción, español-neutral

I heard this proverb once in passing; both in English and Spanish.

> The highest cliff you can fall from is trust

Using Google Translate, I tried to get the Spanish translation (below), but it doesn't sound right.

> El acantilado más alto que puede caer de confianza es

What exactly is wrong with the Spanish translation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I see ([multiple links](http://akifrases.com/frase/139459)), the original quote by Francisco de Quevedo was:

> El mayor despeñadero, la confianza.

---

You probably heard it in English, which probably lost part of its content by the translation, and then tried to translate it back to Spanish. It would be funny to do this over and over again and see what this sentence ends up being : )

Why is this wrong?

> El acantilado más alto que puede caer de confianza es

Note the sentence, if it was written straight, would be *"la confianza es el mayor despeñadero"*. So translating it back is complicated.

First of all, in the translation you provide the verb *"es"* lies at the end of the sentence without much sense. Then, the way it is constructed the subject is *"el acantilado más alto"*, whereas should be *"confianza"*.

Also, it says `El acantilado ... + que + <action> DE confianza <verb>`. If you wanted to write it this way, you should make an extra connexion (I don't know its technical name) and say *"El acantilado más alto **del que** se puede caer **es** la confianza"*.

Comment: In the last bit, the "el" in "del que" is optional, but in this case I feel would be more commonly used than not.